# Excel - We found extra characters at the end of JSON input

Tags: json, excel, parsing

I am trying to import my json file to excel via the get data function. When doing this i get an error saying that "We found extra characters at the end of JSON input"

i ran the json file in jsonformatter and got this additional piece of information:

Parse error on line 1:
...s":"1555615338756"}
{"created_at":"Thu A
-----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'

Edit: line 1

{"created_at":"Thu Apr 18 19:22:18 +0000 2019","id":1118957948263206913,"id_str":"1118957948263206913","text":"Arsenal jersey looks weird. #NapoliArsenal","source":"\u003ca href=\"https://mobile.twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web App\u003c/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":955479430377373696,"id_str":"955479430377373696","name":"Yash Iyer","screen_name":"MesutOziI28","location":"Bengaluru South, India","url":null,"description":"RM,Nerazzurri,BFC,RCB,bcci,rafa nadal and so on! Lately into B99,superstore! Sympathetic liker of tweets!","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":258,"friends_count":454,"listed_count":0,"favourites_count":47788,"statuses_count":5318,"created_at":"Mon Jan 22 16:37:02 +0000 2018","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"F5F8FA","profile_background_image_url":"","profile_background_image_url_https":"","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1DA1F2","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1109886916609007616/9rAavtGh_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1109886916609007616/9rAavtGh_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/955479430377373696/1544903252","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"NapoliArsenal","indices":[28,42]}],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1555615338756"}

Comment: uh... fix the JSON so it validates? not entirely sure where the JSON is coming from nor what the "get data function" is.

Comment: If the error is on line 1 then maybe it would help to show the full content of line 1?  Where is your JSON from?

Comment: looking again, the issue is you have to curly braces without a separator...  `5338756"} {"created_`. Depending on the beginning of line 1 you most likely need a comma between the end and open curly bracket

Comment: @ScottHoltzman post that as an aswer; given the context, that is the only answer i can see... should be able to get this off the unanswered list

Comment: Seems there is [Relaxed JSON](http://www.relaxedjson.org/) sample. And I guess the get data function expects standard JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Forever old, but I was trying to ingest an AWS CloudCheckr JSON into Excel via Power Query and getting the "We found extra characters at the end of JSON input."

**Finally figured out, with the help of https://jsonformatter.org/ that some data was provided as `True` -- without quotes, which Excel PQ needed.  Simple find/replacing `:True,` with `:"True",` did the trick.**

Seriously, Microsoft, you did not recognize Boolean when you found it?  Excel would have had no problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error message:

> Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'

Looking at where `{` appears notice that directly before that is `}`. The JSON has no separator after the closing curly `}` and thus cannot process it because it's looking for one of the following:

- `EOF`
- `}`
- `,`
- `]`

In this case, it most likely needs a `,`. It could also need `],`, if it's an array of items. If neither of those fix it, you will need to post the entire line 1 of your JSON.

Comment: Thank you for the swift replies, and for the effort you have made to help me this far.

None of the suggested fixes worked and therefore i edited the entire line 1 into the question @ScottHoltzman

Comment: @SimenL.N - when i place your JSON into https://jsonformatter.org/ it validates perfectly. It also does not match the error you are showing. `s":"1555615338756"} {"created_at"...`  But a clue is that maybe it's producing 2 sets of the JSON, because a new beginning is come right after the end

Answer (score 0):

I had to do two changes to make this work: changed json body to Pascal case notation even thought it was in Camel case in chrome payload
, and secondly I was returning a simple string to verify the service is working - once I changed that to an object (as a json formatted response) this resolved the error I was getting.